# Windows NT 4.0 od Raspberry Pi 3b+

Tags: windows

Its possible ? And how ? Thx. I searching for best operating system for my pi. I know old Windows systems too NT. Only sugestion.

Comment: what are you asking?

Comment: No. You can run Windows 10 IOT (Arm Edition) on a Raspberry Pi, but not an ordinary Windows. It's an entirely different hardware.

Comment: Even with Windows IoT, the Pi 3B+ has to use the *unsupported* technical preview https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/iot-core/troubleshooting and it’s known to have issues.  The Pi 4 is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

All Microsoft Windows operating systems (except MS Windows 10 IOT) are made and compiled to run on intel microprocessors. These have a complete different instruction set than that ARM processors used for Raspberry Pi. So it is not possible to run MS Windows operating systems direct on a Raspberry Pi. This is also true for MS Windows NT. You can use emulators like **qemu** to translate the instruction set from intel to ARM but on a Raspberry Pi this is annoying slow and not really usable.